# Change app Language with version updated

Tags: ios, localization, app-store-connect

Last year I've joined Apple Store. My app language is english in itunes connect.
I have created the application in turkish. I did not any localizing in my app. I just paste the Turkish text into control such as label, textView and other.

Now I want to show the app language "Turkish" in both itunes connect and app store. 
I have submitted the new version and set "Turkish" localizations in info.plist but nothing did change.
What can I do to fix this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have tried to add the various nationalities of the language in this panel?
[image]